# Pandas change each group into a single row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the follows.

```
>>> data
   target  user  data
0       A     1     0
1       A     1     0
2       A     1     1
3       A     2     0
4       A     2     1
5       B     1     1
6       B     1     1
7       B     1     0
8       B     2     0
9       B     2     0
10      B     2     1
```

You can see that each user may contribute multiple claims about a target. I want to only store each user's most frequent data for each target. For example, for the dataframe shown above, I want the result like follows.

```
>>> result
  target  user  data
0      A     1     0
1      A     2     0
2      B     1     1
3      B     2     0
```

How to do this? And, can I do this using groupby? (my real dataframe is not sorted)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are two equally-frequent claims?

Comment: For each user, among its multiple contributed data for each target, I want to use majority voting to return the most frequently appeared claims

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining this well.  "Majority voting" only determines an output if the votes aren't equal, and so your specification doesn't describe what to do when claims are equally frequent.  For example,  say we fed your rows 1 and 2 to this function.  What datum should it return?  Both 0 and 1 are equally frequent.

Comment: Suppose you fed row 1, row 2 and row3, it should return 0, since 0 appears twice and 1 appears only once.

Comment: @SteveYang that case is obvious.  What happens when there are 4 rows, 2 are 0 and 2 are 1?

Comment: Then, return either 1 or 0

Comment: Okay, I'm out.  :-)  I keep asking you what to do if they appear the same number of times and you keep replying "if they appear a different number of times, you take the one which appears most".   I explicitly ask you what to do if you feed it row 1 and 2, and you instead answer the different question "row 1, row 2, and row 3".  Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. If equal, break tie randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `count` create the helper key , then we using `idxmax`

```
df['helperkey']=df.groupby(['target','user','data']).data.transform('count')
df.groupby(['target','user']).helperkey.idxmax()
Out[10]: 
target  user
A       1       0
        2       3
B       1       5
        2       8
Name: helperkey, dtype: int64
df.loc[df.groupby(['target','user']).helperkey.idxmax()]
Out[11]: 
  target  user  data  helperkey
0      A     1     0          2
3      A     2     0          1
5      B     1     1          2
8      B     2     0          2
```